# Performance of modelling inheritance in database using superclass table

Tags: mysql, performance, database-design, database-performance

My Question, is actually a question about the usability / performance of a concept / idea I had:

**The Setup:**

Troughout my Database, two (actually three) fields always re-appear constantly: `title` and `description` (and `created`). The title is always a `VARCHAR(100)` and the description always a `TEXT`.

Now, to simplify those tables, I thought about something (and changed it in that way): Wouldnt it be more useful to just create a table named `content`, with `id`, `title`,  `description` and `created` as only fields, and always point to that table from all others?

Example:

table `tab` has `id`, `key` and `content_id` (instead of `title`, `description` and `created`)

table `chapter` has `id`, `story_id` and `content_id` (" ")

etc

**The Question:**

Everything works fine so far, but my only fear is performance. Will I run into a bottleneck, doing it this way, or should I be fine? I have about 23 different tables pointing to `content` right now, and some of them will hold user-defined content (journals, comments, etc) - so the number of entries in `content` could get quite high.

Is this setup better, or equal to having `title` and `description` in every separate table?

Edit: And if it turns out to be a bad idea, what are alternatives to mantain/copying certain fields like `title` and `description` into ~25 tables?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Sounds like a pretty good way of doing it to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clear answer for your question because it mainly depends on usage of the tables, so just consider following points:

1. **How often will you need write to the tables?** In case of many inserts/updates having data in one big table can cause problems because all write operations will target the same table.
2. **How often do you need data stored in table with common data?** If `title` or `description` are not needed most of the time for your select this can be OK. If you need `title` every time then take into account that you wile always have to `JOIN` table with common data.
3. **How do you manage your database schema?** It can be easier to write some simple tool for creation/checking table structure. In MySQL you can easily access data dictionary with `DESCRIBE table_name` or through `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` database.

I'm working on project with 700+ tables where some of the fields have to be present in every table (when was record created, timestamp of last modification). We have simple script that helps with this, because having all data in one table would be disastrous.

Comment: Thanks, I decided to split the data table up and add those columns to each table separately. Based on your questions - much more initial work, but probably better in the end (less joins, etc) ;)